# How to append a span as the last object in an li?

Tags: javascript, append, insertafter

I currently have this line of code

```html
<div id="news-articles">
  <ul class="display-posts-listing">
    <li class="listing-item">
      <span></span>
      <span class="category-display"></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I need it to look like this (* note - There are multiple uls. Therefore it has to be each "span.category-display" thats gets appended last inside their own parent li) :

```js
//Ive been trying to use this js script, but so far no results. Can anyone assist? Thanks so much! :





  $("#news-articles .category-display").each(function() {
                $(this).prev("li.listing-item").append(this);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="news-articles">
  <ul class="display-posts-listing">
    <li class="listing-item">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span class="category-display"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.prev()` selects the previous sibling.  You want to use `$.parent()`

I would write it like this instead:

```
$(".listing-item").each(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    var $elem = $this.find(".category-display").detach();
    $elem.appendTo($this);
});
```

Comment: This Worked! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just append the span to the LI, and it will end up at the bottom

```js
$('.listing-item').append(function() {
  return $(this).find('.category-display');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="news-articles">
  <ul class="display-posts-listing">
    <li class="listing-item">
      <span>1</span>
      <span class="category-display">4</span>
      <span>2</span>
      <span>3</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <br />
  <ul class="display-posts-listing">
    <li class="listing-item">
      <span>1</span>
      <span class="category-display">4</span>
      <span>2</span>
      <span>3</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```